# Can we bind angular values with self created HTML properties?

Tags: angular

**HTML**

```
 <div commentId = {{commentData.id}} class="addReplyContainer" style="display: none" >
              <textarea  style="width:50%" class="addReplyTextarea form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
```

**Component**

```
 /** 
   * reply link is clicked
   * @param event
   */
  addReply(event, commentId);
  addReply(event, commentId)
  {
    console.log(commentId);
    jQuery('div[commentId='+commentId+']').show(); // Want to use CommentId here


  }
```

I want to do some DOM manipulation using Jquery Library within Angular 4.4.
But it looks like I cannot assign new properties to DOM elements where we want to use angular variables.

**ERROR**

> ncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'commentId' since
>   it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("

Any other way to solve this problem?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried attribute binding like `[attr.commentId]="commentData.id"`?

Comment: Let me try. @yurzui

Comment: @yurzui Wow. It worked. Thanks For saving my life! You are genius, saviour.

Comment: It's basic knowledge that you can get after reading documentation:)

Comment: Ok. I will try to read in detail next time before posting. May be confused due to deadline. I will see if this question help someone or it get down vote else I will delete it. Thanks a ton again.